# Finding n nearest data points to grid locations

Tags: python

I'm working on a problem where I have a large set (>4 million) of data points located in a three-dimensional space, each with a scalar function value.  This is represented by four arrays: XD, YD, ZD, and FD.  The tuple (XD[i], YD[i], ZD[i]) refers to the location of data point i, which has a value of FD[i].

I'd like to superimpose a rectilinear grid of, say, 100x100x100 points in the same space as my data.  This grid is set up as follows.

```
[XGrid, YGrid, ZGrid] = np.mgrid[Xmin:Xmax:Xstep, Ymin:Ymax:Ystep, Zmin:Zmax:Zstep]
XG = XGrid[:,0,0]
YG = YGrid[0,:,0]
ZG = ZGrid[0,0,:]
```

XGrid is a 3D array of the x-value at each point in the grid.  XG is a 1D array of the x-values going from Xmin to Xmax, separated by a distance of XStep.

I'd like to use an interpolation algorithm I have to find the value of the function at each grid point based on the data surrounding it.  In this algorithm I require 20 data points closest (or at least close) to my grid point of interest.  That is, for grid point (XG[i], YG[j], ZG[k]) I want to find the 20 closest data points.

The only way I can think of is to have one for loop that goes through each data point and a subsequent embedded for loop going through all (so many!) data points, calculating the Euclidean distance, and picking out the 20 closest ones.

```
for i in range(0,XG.shape):
  for j in range(0,YG.shape):
    for k in range(0,ZG.shape):

      Distance = np.zeros([XD.shape])

      for a in range(0,XD.shape):
        Distance[a] = (XD[a] - XG[i])**2 + (YD[a] - YG[j])**2 + (ZD[a] - ZG[k])**2

      B = np.zeros([20], int)
      for a in range(0,20):
        indx = np.argmin(Distance)
        B[a] = indx
        Distance[indx] = float(inf)
```

This would give me an array, B, of the indices of the data points closest to the grid point.  I feel like this would take too long to go through each data point at each grid point.

I'm looking for any suggestions, such as how I might be able to organize the data points before calculating distances, which could cut down on computation time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to iterate over your data points for each grid location: Your grid locations are inherently ordered, so just iterate over your data points *once*, and assign each data point to the eight grid locations that surround it. When you're done, some grid locations may have too few data points. Check the data points of adjacent grid locations. If you have plenty of data points to go around (it depends on how your data is distributed), you can already select the 20 closest neighbors during the initial pass.

*Addendum:* You may want to reconsider other parts of your algorithm as well. Your algorithm is a kind of piecewise-linear interpolation, and there are plenty of relatively simple improvements. Instead of dividing your space into evenly spaced cubes, consider allocating a number of center points and dynamically repositioning them until the average distance of data points from the nearest center point is minimized, like this:

1. Allocate each data point to its closest center point.
2. Reposition each center point to the coordinates that would minimize the average distance from "its" points (to the "centroid" of the data subset).
3. Some data points now have a different closest center point. Repeat steps 1. and 2. until you converge (or near enough).

Comment: I'm going to give it a go with the rectilinear grid first and then think about how I might go about your addendum suggestion.
I've assigned each data point to a block sectioned off by the nearest eight grid points.  I'd like to now go through each grid point and find the nearest twenty data.  For an internal grid point I can see how I would go about doing this(searching the eight surrounding blocks and out), but I'm not sure how to deal with points near the volume's boundary.  For example, gridpoint (0,0,0) will give an index-out-of-range error if I try to call the eight surrounding blocks.

Comment: My suggestion was to assign each data point to all eight surrounding grid locations; then you can simply pick the 20 closest for each location. A less exact algorithm would be to section off the space into cubes that are *centered* at the grid points (rather than having grid points at their corners).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at a seemingly simmilar but 2D [problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) and see if you cannot improve with ideas from there.

From the top of my head, I'm thinking that you can sort the points according to their coordinates (three separate arrays). When you need the closest points to the `[X, Y, Z]` grid point you'll quickly locate points in those three arrays and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you don't really need the euclidian distance, since you are only interested in relative distance, which can also be described as:

```
abs(deltaX) + abs(deltaY) + abs(deltaZ)
```

And save on the expensive power and square roots...